# Collection to method parameters?

Tags: java, methods, collections, parameters

We have a method:

```
public void foo (String s1, String s2, String s3) { 
    ...
}
```

And a collection of choice. Maybe hashmap, maybe list, doesn't matter.

Is there a way to "convert" collection to method paramterers? Something like:

```
public void foo (getParamters(map)) { ... }
```

Yes, ofcourse I could do

```
public void foo (map.get(0), map.get(1), map.get(3)) { ... }
```

but I'm thinking about something a bit more automatic, that could help me with a bigger problem.

Comment: Make an overloaded method that takes a Collrction as parameter and calls your method with the extracted parameters.

Answer (score 5):

You can convert the Collection to an array and pass the array to the method :

```
public void foo (String... s) { 
    ...
}

...

String[] arr = map.keySet().toArray (new String[0]);
foo (arr);
```

Since you don't know beforehand the number of elements in your Collection, declaring the method with varargs makes more sense then a fixed number of arguments as you have in `foo (String s1, String s2, String s3)`.

Comment: To extend this for *other types* instead of just `String`.. You could pass an array of objects and do a `instanceof` check inside the method before extracting parameters :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use varargs for example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    test("1", "2");
    test("1", "2", "3");

}

public static void test(String ...args){
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use varargs, it allows the method to accept zero or multiple arguments. If we don't know how many argument we will have to pass in the method, varargs is the better approach.

**Syntax:**

```
return_type method_name(data_type... variableName){
  // code snippet
}
```

Example :

```
public void varargsMethod(String... values){          
    for(String s:values){  
       System.out.println(s);  
    }  
}
```

Running [example](http://ideone.com/ISwFzA)